# Appengine 405 Method POST Is not allowed

Tags: python-2.7, google-app-engine

I'm learning how to write web app using appengine using Python and got 
405 Method Not Allowed
The method POST is not allowed for this resource.

```
form = """
<form method="post"> 
  What is yor birthday?
  <br>  
  <label> Month
    <input type = "text" name = "month">
  </label>
  <label> Day
    <input type = "text" name = "day">
  </label>
  <label> Year
    <input type = "text" name = "year">
  </label>

  <br>
  <br>
  <input type = "submit">
</form>"""
    class MainPage(webapp2.RequestHandler):
        def get(self):
            self.response.write(form)

        def post(self):
            self.response.out.write("Got The Date")


    app = webapp2.WSGIApplication([('/', MainPage)], debug=True)
```

I have post method in my code, so what is the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I run that sample (after adding the missing import), I get a stack trace that ends with

```
   class MainPage(webapp2.RequestHandler):
   ^
IndentationError: unexpected indent
```

Try fixing your indentation, and pay attention to what's showing up in the logs.

The error you're seeing could also be explained by inconsistent indentation (say, if the `post` method was indented at the same level as the class).

Comment: Thanks a lot, that happened because i used notepad++, when i checked in IDLE I realized tge same error.